# How to compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{\int_0^x \frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}dt}{x^{2n+1}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the function

$$f(x)=(-1)^{n+1} \frac{\int_0^x \frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}dt}{x^{2n+1}}$$

How do we compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)$?

Here is my attempt

If $t\geq 0$ then $\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2} \leq t^{2n+2}$ and if $t\leq 0$ then $t^{2n+2}\leq\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}$. That is, for any $t$

$$-|t|^{2n+2}\leq\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\leq |t|^{2n+2}$$

Thus

$$-\int_0^x|t|^{2n+2}\leq\int_0^x\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\leq \int_0^x|t|^{2n+2}$$

$$-\frac{|x|^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\leq\int_0^x\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\leq \frac{|x|^{2n+3}}{2n+3}$$

$$-\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\leq\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\int_0^x\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\leq \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|^{2n+3}}{2n+3}$$

$$0\leq\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\int_0^x\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\leq 0$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\int_0^x\frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}=0$$

With this result in hand, we go back to the original limit.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{\int_0^x \frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}dt}{x^{2n+1}}$$

$$=(-1)^{n+1}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^x \frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}dt}{x^{2n+1}}$$

$$=\frac{0}{0}$$

By L'Hopital's Rule

$$=(-1)^{n+1}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x^{2n+2}}{1+x^2}}{(2n+1)x^{2n}}$$

$$=(-1)^{n+1}\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{(2n+1)(1+x^2)}$$

$$=0$$

is this calculation correct? I know the result is correct, but I am interested in the steps.

For context, $f(x)$ is the remainder in a Taylor Polynomial of the $\arctan$ function. The book I am reading (Spivak's *Calculus*) skipped over the details of this calculation.

Comment: The integral in your question appears as remainder in Taylor expansion of $\arctan x$. That should help you out.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes I know, see the final paragraph of my post.

Comment: You may also use the inequality $1-t^2<1/(1+t^2)<1$.

Comment: You are spending a lot of effort showing $\lim_{x\to 0}\int_0^xh(t)\,dt=0.$ This is true for any $h$ which is Riemann-integrable. The integral is continuous as a function of $x,$ so it is, in particular, continuous at $x=0,$ and hence the limit is $0.$

Comment: I really don't understand the need for lHospital here. Since the function under limit is even it is sufficient to consider only  positive $x$. The factor $(-1)^{n+1}$ can be taken out of limit operation and remaining factor is less than $\frac{1}{x^{2n+1}}\int_0^x t^{2n+2}\,dt=\frac{x^2}{2n+3}$ so that it tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand ${1\over 1+t^2}$ as a geometric series as $x \rightarrow 0$.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {1\over x^{2n+1}}{\int_{0}^{x}{t^{2n+2} \over {1+t^2}}dt}\space =\space\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {1\over x^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k}\int_{0}^{x}{t^{2n+2k+2}dt}$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {1\over x^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\cdot x^{2n+2k+3}\over(2n+2k+3)}=\space\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\cdot x^{2k+2}\over(2n+2k+3)}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

*Too much advanced but this is just for your curiosity.*

Sonner or later, you will learns that

$$\int \frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{t^{2 n+1} }{2 n+1}\left(1-\,
   _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{2};n+\frac{3}{2};-t^2\right)\right)$$ where appears the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).
$$\int_0^x \frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{x^{2 n+1} }{2 n+1}\left(\,
   _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{2};n+\frac{3}{2};-x^2\right)-1\right)$$
$$R=\frac{\int_0^x \frac{t^{2n+2}}{1+t^2}\,dt }{x^{2n+1}}=\frac{1 }{2 n+1}\left(\,
   _2F_1\left(1,n+\frac{1}{2};n+\frac{3}{2};-x^2\right)-1\right)$$ Developed as a series around $x=0$ gives
$$R=\sum_{p=1}^\infty (-1)^p\frac{ x^{2 p}}{2 n+2 p+1}=-\frac {x^2}{2n+3}+O(x^4)$$
Not truncated, $R$ is another special function.